# c++ std::lock_guard scope reach

Tags: c++, mutex, locks

let's assume I have a function that acquires a lock and executes a fuction passed by argument:

```
template <typename T>
T acquireLock(std::mutex& _lock, const std::function<T()>& execution) {

  try {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mutex (_lock);

    return execution();

  } catch (std::logic_error& error) {

    std::cerr << "[exception caught]\n\t" << error.what() << std::endl;

  }

  return false;
}
```

Also, I have a class that needs to acquire said lock for some of it's methods.

```
class MyThreadSafeClass {

 public:

  bool Init();
  bool StopApi();
  unsigned int GetValue() {

      auto ret = acquireLock<unsigned int>(_lock, [this]() -> unsigned int {

        // does some work that's not thread-safe...
        return value;

      });

      return ret;
  }

 private:

  bool _ready = false;
  std::mutex _lock;

};
```

My doubt is if whenever I call `GetValue()`, looking at my `acquireLock()` method, is the `execution()` call also affected by the lock scope ?

```
auto myClass = new MyThreadSafeClass();
myClass->GetValue();
```

Looking at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), more specifically:

> When a lock_guard object is created, it attempts to take ownership of
> the mutex it is given. When control leaves the scope in which the
> lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the
> mutex is released.

It's still unclear to me if what happens inside `execution()` code is still affected by the lock scope.

Comment: It is ... It runs within the scope of the lock_guard. Its scope is until the return is executed and that doesn't happen until `execute` has been executed.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking exactly.  The `lock_guard` is constructed first, acquiring the mutex lock.  Then `execution()` is called, while the mutex is locked.  When `execution()` exits, the `lock_guard` goes out of scope, releasing the mutex lock.

Comment: Do you mean what happens, when the function `execution` tries to aquire the same lock itself when it is called?

Comment: No, @RemyLebeau answered exactly what I mean to ask! Quoting: "When execution() exits, the lock_guard goes out of scope, releasing the mutex lock".
Sorry for the confusion, I understood now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[stmt.return]/p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#3):

> 3. The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables ([stmt.jump]) of the block enclosing the return statement.

So we get:

1. The mutex is locked
2. `execution()` is called while holding the lock
3. The lock is released
4. The evaluated value is returned to the caller (or the `catch` clause is entered)

In other words yes, it will work as intended.

---

Unrelated note: `std::function` isn't very efficient. Templating on the callable type should work better:

```
template<typename F>
auto doLocked(std::mutex& _lock, F const& f) -> decltype(f()) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_lock);
    return f();
}
```